How can I safely modify a file on an XFS filesystem mounted by a different or hibernated system?
Recently I broke my system by modifying a configuration file such that the root user would no longer accept login due to PAM crashing. I did not want to power off the system, and instead wanted to hibernate it, modify the configuration file from the initramfs, and then resume.
Needless to say this is ill-advised, but it appears to be doable. How can I modify a file on an XFS (or any) filesystem, without mounting or corrupting the filesystem if it is presently mounted elsewise?

For XFS, the command xfs_bmap or xfs_bmap -v can be used to identify the block ranges of all the extents of a file. Other filesystems have similar commands. I had corrupted my /etc/security/limits.conf file and had this output:
$ xfs_bmap -v /etc/security/limits.conf
/etc/security/limits.conf:
 EXT: FILE-OFFSET      BLOCK-RANGE          AG AG-OFFSET          TOTAL
   0: [0..7]:          391598456..391598463  3 (2529656..2529663)     8

The output indicates the file is up to 8 blocks long starting at block 391598456. My blocks were 512 bytes long, which I found by trial and error with likely powers of 2.
So I can see my file content with:
# dd if=/dev/my/block/device bs=512 skip=391598456 count=7

This reads it straight from the block device rather than going through the filesystem driver. It works fine if the filesystem is not mounted.
I backed up the output of xfs_bmap as well as the contents of the file, and then I modified the contents of the backup to repair the corruption, and saved this as a new file.
Because I am not altering the metadata of the filesystem, the old file and the repaired file must be the exact same length:
$ ls -l limits.conf.*
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 2703 Dec 14 15:38 limits.conf.new
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 2703 Dec 14 15:38 limits.conf.old
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user  171 Dec 14 15:37 limits.conf.xfs_bmap.txt

See, they are both 2703 bytes long.
These file operations can be performed on the live system, or the filesystem can be mounted read-only (while live on one system) from another system. However, XFS appears to replay a log by default when the filesystem is mounted read-only, so there would likely be a little filesystem corruption if this data is collected from a different system, unless the log replay is disabled or inhibited somehow. It may work to make a read-only loop device mount of the device to prevent writes to it. I didn't look into disabling the log replay at this time myself.
This was a dracut-based system and I could get into a rescue shell, despite inability to login as root and the system being hibernated, by adding noresume rd.break=pre-mount to the kernel commandline. I was working with a language model for help, but I ended up needing to look at dracut's sourcefiles in /usr/lib/dracut/modules.d on the live system or /bin in the initramfs, to find all the commandline options. Without noresume, rd.break=pre-mount would have no effect.
In the emergency shell, I could then engage the data by using the offsets from the output of xfs_bmap. To reduce the chance of corrupting other data, I stored the needed values in shell variables:
OFFSET=391598456
BS=512
COUNT=7

Then I can verify I have the correct data:
dd if=/dev/my/block/device bs=$BS count=$COUNT skip=$OFFSET

And write new data back in!
dd if=limits.conf.new of=/dev/my/block/device conv=notrunc bs=$BS count=$COUNT seek=$OFFSET

It's important here to get the skip and seek parameter names correct. One is for input, and the other for output. I use conv=notrunc as a safe habit whenever writing partway into existing data, but it is likely not possible to truncate a block device.
Back in the live system, the old data is still cached and must be refreshed from disk. I was able to use dd iflag=direct to do this:
dd iflag=direct if=/etc/security/limits.conf

And then PAM stopped breaking and I could use my repaired system again, without ever shutting down the desktop or closing any of my open documents.
